# How to add to specific item in a list in a CSV file

Tags: python, list, csv

How to add/modify a specific item in a list in a CSV file

```
1,2,5,x
1,5,7,x
6,5,9,x
```

How to add the second and third Item of each row and save the Result in x of each row in python?

Comment: Is this a *list*? Or a csv?

Comment: Csv wihtout  the square brackets ...list inside list

Comment: @عبداللهشريفمحمد Do see my answer and let me know if you have any doubts

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the solution opening the csv file, changing the values in memory and then writing back the changes to disk.

```
r = csv.reader(open('/tmp/test.csv')) # Here your csv file
lines = list(r)
```

Content of lines:

```
[[1,2,5,0],#0 value is to be replaced
 [1,5,7,0],
 [6,5,9,0]]
```

Modifying the x values for the first row, in our case where `0` is:

```
lines[0][3] =  lines[0][1] + lines[0][2]
```

Content of lines:

```
[[1,2,5,7],#value changed here
 [1,5,7,0],
 [6,5,9,0]]
```

Now we only have to write it back to a file

```
writer = csv.writer(open('/tmp/output.csv', 'w'))
writer.writerows(lines)
```

You need to follow the same logic for all other rows. Ideally using a for loop, e.g.

```
for i in range(len(lines)):
   lines[i][3] = lines[0][1] + lines[0][2]
```